# Core Data Entity Name Not Found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have made a a datamodel with an entity named "Status". I also created the appropriate classes so I can use the property's to get the attributes. But it doesn't seem like my app can find my datamodel :S

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:            (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Database test.
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext; 
    Blabla *t =  [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Status"     inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

I took the relevant code out. It stops on the last line giving me this error:

+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'Status' in this model.'

I double checked the names. I really have an entity called Status. I dont get it :S I also checked if the data model is in my compile source. It is...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like this is running just as the application launches, I am guessing you have not set up your managed object model and your persistent store coordinator before you created the NSManagedObjectContext...

So try something like:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
NSManagedObjectModel* managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

NSURL *documentsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *dbURL = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"myModel.sqlite"];

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:dbURL options:nil error:&error]) {
    // handle error
}

NSManagedObject *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
Blabla *t =  [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Status" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

...

(release everything when you are done)
```

Of course, in a real application, you will probably want to keep these around as properties or instance variables in the application delegate and release them in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already had that code within my appDelegate. But I found the solution to the problem ^^ My model had to have the exact same name as my app... I called it data....momd Which isn't the same :) I could also change it in the model method ^^

Comment: I'm glad you solved you problem, although I am pretty sure that the data model does not need to have the same name as your app...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I believe this is an issue with the Model Configuration. If anyone sees this post, check to see if the entity is in the "Default" configuration, or if you've added a different configuration, make sure the entity in question is added to the correct configuration.